# Getting a wrong name format when doing a scraping on PHP

Tags: php, web-scraping

Now I'm doing a scraping for get a facebook name. if the facebook name is written on thai language. It return with code format. Here is the code

```
$url = "https://www.facebook.com/7elevenqueen";

$client = new Client();
$response = $client->get($url, ['headers' => ['User-Agent' => 'spider']);

preg_match_all('/<meta([^>]+)content="([^>]+)>/', $response->getBody(), $getData);

$name = mb_convert_encoding(str_replace('&amp;', '&', substr($getData[2][9], 0, -3)), 'UTF-8');
```

it return this

```
&#xe40;&#xe08;&#xe49;&#xe32;&#xe41;&#xe21;&#xe48;&#xe40;&#xe0b;&#xe40;&#xe27;&#xe48;&#xe19;
```

that is wrong. it should display name `เจ้าแม่เซเว่น`.

How do I enable to get the correct name like this `เจ้าแม่เซเว่น`?

This is happen only on Thai language. If the name is written with alphabet, no problem with that.

please help.

Comment: These are numeric HTML character references, so you can simply decode them using https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: FYI: Facebook does not allow scraping (unless you had their explicit prior written content) - so don't be too surprised if you find your server IP blocked by them after doing this a number of times.

Comment: yes i understand that. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use `html_entity_decode` on the result. e.g.

`html_entity_decode($name);`